# django css and js files

Tags: django

I am unable to use CSS and JS files in my django project.

Folder structure:

```
mysite/
mysite/mysite/settings.py
mysite/mysite/templates/base.html
mysite/mysite/assets/css/...
```

settings.py

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = 'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',...)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

base.html

running python manage.py collectstatic returns:

```
"Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?
```

Comment: Where is your static folder? Have you run `collectstatic`? `STATIC_URL` should be `/static/`

Comment: also, `STATIC_ROOT` should have a trailing `/`: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static/')`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You never *manually* put anything `STATIC_ROOT`. It is only a dumping ground for `collectstatic` *in production*; it shouldn't even exist in development.

All of your static resources need to go in one of your apps' `static` directories, or if you need project-wide resources, you must create an entirely different directory for that is not the same as either `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATIC_ROOT` and add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'assets'),
)
```

You can call it whatever you want; I typically use "assets". Just don't name it "static", "media", "site_media", etc., just to avoid confusion.

Comment: I moved the files to mysite/mysite/assets, changed static_files_dirs as you described, but I get ""Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Your STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list; perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?"

Comment: If you copied and pasted what I had, you would not be getting that error. What did you change?

Comment: I moved the assets folder so that it matches the path of PROJECT_PATH , that's it.

Comment: hhmmm adding the "," after os.path.join() did the trick it seams. Weird

Comment: @kristiannissen yes, because `(1,)` is a tuple (as required for that particular setting) whereas `(1)` is interpreted as `1`.

Comment: What do you mean? This is the same in every environment.